# Why is !==0 returning values equal to 0 rather than not equal to 0?

Tags: javascript

I have the following bit of code that is meant to return values between 13 & -13 that do NOT add up to 0.  The following is the bit of javascript in question (I included the full JsFiddle below):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function GenerateRandomNumber() {
    var min = -13,
      max = 13;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return random;
  }
  var x = GenerateRandomNumber();

  function GenerateRandomNumber2() {
    var min2 = -13,
      max2 = 13;
    var random2;
    while ((random2 + x) !== 0) {
      random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max2 - min2 + 1)) + min2;
    }
    return random2;
  }
  var xx = GenerateRandomNumber2();
  $('#x').html(x);
  $('#xx').html(xx);
  $('#y').html(sum);
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vL77hjp0/

However, it seems to be returning values that are equal to 0. I cannot figure out why "!==" is doing the opposite of what I intend it to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read your code. You're saying, as long as the sum is nonzero, choose a new random number. That means it will only stop looping when the sum *is* zero.

Comment: I understand now. I was interpreting while to mean "such that."  i.e. "find a new number such that the sum is not 0."

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is going to continue trying to find values while the value is not 0. I.e. when you get values that don't sum to 0 then continue.

Answer (score 0):

Random2 starts off equal to zero, because you haven't set it to have a value.
You then check to see if it's not zero. It is zero, so nothing happens.
Then you return Random2 which is still zero.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the "while" to a "do while" because you need to generate a random number first and check after if the sum is zero. Thus, I changed the condition too.

```
do {
    random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max2 - min2)) + min2;
} while ((random2 + x) === 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works...I'm just a bit confused as to why it works. In layman's terms, I'm interpreting this to mean "do { find a random number} such that (the sum of this random number and the previous number is equal to 0)." In reality, however, it's finding a random number while the same of the random number and the previous number is NOT equal to 0. It seems like it should work with a "!==" rather than a "===." Why is that the case? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind - I think I get it. It's saying, "as long as random + x is equal to 0, keep looking for a new number."